# Math behind computing world space view direction - cg shader Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Can someone please point me to the explanation behind computing world space view direction using following equation:

```
float3 worldSpaceViewDir = _WorldSpaceCameraPos.xyz - worldPos;
```

1. Why do we subtract worldspacePos from worldspaceCameraPos to get viewDirection.
2. May be, I should ask what exactly is world-space view direction?

When I try to do the math, following is what I get.
Example :
A point is located at (0,5,0) world-position and camera is located at (0,0,50) world-position and to get world-viewDirection:

```
worldSpaceViewDir = _WorldSpaceCameraPos.xyz - worldPos
= (0,0,50) - (0,5,0)
= (0,-5,50)
```

[image]
Howcome this is view direction?

Answer (score 3):

```
float3 worldSpaceViewDir = _WorldSpaceCameraPos.xyz - worldPos;
```

This gives the direction from the object position in world coordinates, to the camera position in world coordinates.

I guess you would expect that data to be where the camera is looking.
In terms of shader, you would not think about it this way, it does not matter.

Consider you want a pixel to show white when camera is right in front of it (and black when looking away). You would do a dot product product to see if direction is aligned with normal, but whether the camera is looking at it or not does not matter. Your pixel gets the info and if the camera is facing then it will render but until then, the shader does not care and does what it should.

Note that there is already this method in CG:

```
float3 WorldSpaceViewDir (float4 v)
```

Comment: Thank you fafase!
I get the dot product part of calculation (as used to calculate Fresnel). But I am trying to understand Cartesian/ geometric explanation of :

    float3 worldSpaceViewDir = _WorldSpaceCameraPos.xyz - worldPos;

Comment: It is the vector from the vertex (or pixel) to the camera. This is regardless of the normal of the vertex (or pixel) or the direction of the camera.